Could not find a declaration file for module 'jsonwebtoken'. -pathname- implicitly has an 'any' type
I was working on a backend project, using node.js and express.js.
I need to use the json web token, after installing it via npm i jsonwebtoken I get in my node_modules.
The problem is this when I require that module in my project is says :
Could not find a declaration file for module 'jsonwebtoken'. 'c:/Web Development/Odin Project/Projects/Blog_Api/backend_api/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Try npm i --save-dev @types/jsonwebtoken if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'jsonwebtoken';`ts(7016)":

Also before the module I see 3 dots.
I have tried installing it as dev dependencies but no luck.
I have watched tutorials about using json web token and they didn't face this issue.

Have you tried what the warning suggests? npm i --save-dev @types/jsonwebtoken The module exists and even without it you can use the jsonwebtoken module. It just says there are to typescript definitions. Install the module above or ignore the message.
